# What rules should I set in my firestore rules to only let the users with that userID view the book with the same userID?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want the user to only see books with the same userID as its own userID. What do I set rules to? For reference here is my current rules but it allows access to everyoes books once logged in.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /booklist/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add the request.auth.uid == userID feature but it is not working when I try to add it.

For reference, here is my collection 'booklist' where you can see the userID field indicated.
[image]

Comment: Is that really something for the rules? As part of the (book) document, I think I would add it to the query.

Comment: Swift example:

// Create a reference to the booklist collection
let booklistRef = db.collection("booklist")

// Create a query against the collection.
let query = booklistRef.whereField("userID", isEqualTo: "oRtlnrklJ2KFoAn5J")

Comment: "*But it is not working when I try to add it*".  Your question show show what exactly you tried and describe what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  You should also show the code in the client app, as you could be doing something wrong there as well.  Overall, questions on stack overflow should contain a minimal complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can set rules according to you in firebase which collection you want to make accessible or how much nested but to get user-specific data use can use where clause.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your rules for that would be:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID
```

Combined with this query in your code (because [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters)  on their own):

```
db.collection("booklist").where("userID", "==", user.uid).get()
```

I highly recommend reading the documentation on [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access) and [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query), specifically [securing and querying documents based on a field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_a_field)